# USB NAS box disconnects when inserting/removing flash card from reader

Tags: windows, windows-xp, nas

My friend is running Windows XP SP3 32-bit.  We have a NAS box attached via USB. (Sorry didn't get the make of the NAS)  When we put his compact flash card from his camera into his card reader, everything works fine.  However, when he goes to remove his flash card (using the `safely remove hardware` app from the systray), all of his connected devices, especially the NAS, disconnect.